# Send multipart/form-data with axios in AWS Lambda function: source.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, lambda, multipartform-data

I have a lambda function written in node js. My front end application is sending formdata in the body as a POST request to my lambda function. The goal of the lambda is to send the formData to a backend service. My issue is I don't know how to process the formdata within the lambda function.

I have the following modules packages: lambda-multipart-parser and form-data.

This is the output of the lambda-parser:

```
const parser = require('lambda-multipart-parser');

// inside of handler

const result = await parser.parse(event);
console.log('result',result)
```

Result:

```
result {
  files: [
    {
      content: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 01 2c 01 2c 00 00 ff e1 03 66 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 09 01 0f 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 ... 141038 more bytes>,
      filename: 'IMG_0037 - Copy.JPG',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      fieldname: 'files'
    },
    {
      content: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 01 2c 01 2c 00 00 ff e1 03 66 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 09 01 0f 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 ... 141038 more bytes>,
      filename: 'IMG_0037.JPG',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      fieldname: 'files'
    }
  ]
```

Then I append the results to form data and try and make the request:

```
// Add files to formData
    const formData = new FormData();


    result.files.forEach(file => {
        formData.append('files', file);
    });

    const formHeaders = formData.getHeaders();


    formData.submit({
        host: www.example.com,
        headers: formHeaders
    })
```

I then get the following error: **source.on is not a function**

I've looked online and tried quite a few different things but I can't seem to get this to work.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank You

**EDIT**
Complete stack trace

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
    at FormData.append (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:75:3)
    at C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\.webpack\service\src\upload\handler.js:1:3543
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at r.handler (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\.webpack\service\src\upload\handler.js:1:3529)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async InProcessRunner.run (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\handler-runner\in-process-runner\InProcessRunner.js:211:24)
    at async LambdaFunction.runHandler (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\LambdaFunction.js:355:20)
    at async hapiHandler (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\HttpServer.js:533:18)
    at async module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:45:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:312:32)
    at async Request._execute (C:\Users\206591256\Documents\Personal\Sage-Projects\Eagle\football\eagle-api\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:221:9)
offline: (λ: upload) RequestId: ckxajn1hn0002i4nwegzrbsx5  Duration: 283.18 ms  Billed Duration: 284 ms
```

Comment: What is the specification of the service which receive the formData? Could share the complete stacktrace of error?

Comment: Added the complete stacktrace to the ticket